# c# and IIS programming

Tags: c#

I created a small c# console application in which my app.config file will look like below.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="WebRoot" value="webroot" />
    <add key="TempDir" value="temp" />
    <add key="ServerPort" value="8086" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>
```

And from the browser i use the URL http:\localhost:8086\user\login
To process this i used Tiny HTTP server (freesource), now instead of this i want to write the url process using IIS.
Please give me some simple examples or some google url's where i can refer.
But it will be good if i get a simple program.
Thanks in advance
Ramya

Comment: you want to host your program in iis? it's very hard to understand what problems you have

Comment: Actually HTTP Process is currently handling by TinyHttpserver.Now instaed of tinyhttp code want to use IIS for this process, like get and post.

Comment: What kind of process are you talking about? What your console app doing(code would be useful)? `"instaed of tinyhttp code"` what code(also show)?

Comment: It isn't possible to answer this question with the information provided.  *What* are you trying to host on IIS?  What is a "url process"?  What does the console application have to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you want to host your application in IIS. If that is the case you can create a web application rather than console app and directly deploy it on IIS. See the below link:

[How to deploy on IIS 7](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/IIS7ASPNet.aspx)

Comment: No, i cannot create webapplication, because the application should run as service and is already done, rewriting entire code is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use the console app to host your service instead? It will then be easily accessible as a URL. Try the WebGet attribute, maybe?